# Tableau is combining worksheet rows when a zero is present in the data

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a Tableau Worksheet that appears to be combining two rows when a zero percent value is present in one specific line of the source data.  The source data in Excel and the imported data in Tableau appear correct and in valid formats (percentage in excel and text in Tableau).  Other columns handle zeros fine and any other value in this particular row and column works properly as well.

I've included an image of the Data Source tab and the Worksheet in question.  There is a red box around the Data Source row/column of issue and also a red box around the Worksheet area of issue where the data seems to be combined.[image: Tableau Screenshot]

Comment: Tableau is merging the cells because they have the same value... a very boring feature! Does your data source look exactly how you paste into the question or have a row number value? If you have a row number value just drag it and drop it into the "Detail" square into the Marks Shelf.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion - there is a row number table named '0' but it doesn't separate out the combined fields when I drag it to the marks shelf.  The original creator had the first column '1' sorted by field '0' ascending which seems to work unless there's a zero value in the specific row I identified; in which case the zero values in the rows shown combine for some reason.